# Constructing points in a triangle

Tags: geometry

[OH] is an altitude segment in triangle MOR which is right at O.
Let D be a point on [OM] and E be a point of [OR] such that [OH] passes through the midpoint of [DE].
The question is to justify the construction of D and E.
I tried to say that they should be put as OE=OD and HD=HE to have (HO) as a perpendicular bisector of ED.

Comment: $OE=OD$ is not the correct answer. Draw a right triangle where one side is much longer than the other, say with leg lengths 1 and 10. Upon drawing an altitude, and choosing D and E equidistant from O, you will recognize that the altitude does not pass through the midpoint of DE.

Comment: Or can i say that the midpoint of DE should be placed so that the distance from O to it is equal to half of DE, but till now i didn't find the proper way for the construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw $DE$ so that $\angle ODE=\angle MOH$. If $M$ is the intersection between $DE$ and $OH$ then triangles $ODM$ and $OEM$ are isosceles and $DM=ME$ as required.